# Existence of smallest circle containing a polygon

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given a convex polygon $P$, is there a way to find the smallest (meaning, with the smallest possible radius) circle containing $P$? It seems clear that it must exist and that it must go through (at least) one vertex of $P$. In my mind, it makes sense that it has to go through (at least) two vertices of $P$, but I haven't got a proof yet. Of course, if $P$ is cyclic, we already know what happens, but what about in any other case? Also… is it unique?

Comment: By circcumference do you mean circle?  The polygon itself is a circumference containing it.  If $P$ is not convex you would be looking for the convex hull.  If you do mean circle, it must go through three vertices of $P$ and those will define the circle.  You can just take all sets of three vertices of $P$, construct the circle going through them, and take the smallest that includes all the other vertices inside or on it.

Comment: If it's the smallest radius containing P, should'nt all the vertices lie on the circle? For a triangle, the center is defined by the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors

Comment: @JohnGlennLambayon `should'nt all the vertices lie on the circle?` Not necessarily, nor could they in general. Think of a non-rectangle parallelogram for example.

Comment: If the points aren't concyclic, the circle is to two or three vertices, depending on the configurations.

Answer (score 3):

We can reduce the problem of finding the smallest circle around a polygon to that of finding the smallest circle around the polygon's vertices only.

Computing the [smallest enclosing circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) for a set of points is a well-studied problem, and does not need computing the convex hull. Welzl's algorithm (described in the link) does this in randomised linear time. In particular, the smallest circle is unique and passes through at least two vertices of the polygon – three in general, four or more in special cases.

Comment: Is the problem simpler when the hull is known (which is the case here) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust You'd get the same running time either way.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the three or four "special cases": It is obvious that an unlimited number of vertices will lie on the circle if those points are selected to lie on that circle and any additional vertices lie inside the circle.